# How to specify test task run by Gradle SonarQube plugin

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I am using Gradle with the sonarqube plugin and triggering it using

```
gradle sonarqube
```

However, it is calling the built in "test" task which runs all types of tests including the integration tests which do not all pass at the moment. I want to be able to specify that the sonarqube task use something like a "unitTest" task instead of the "test" task which runs everything.

Other people on the team run cucumber tests within the IDE which also uses the test task, so currently when I exclude cucumber tests in the main "test" task, they have to comment that excludes out in order for their cucumber tests to be kicked off, which is not ideal.

I am including sonarqube using the below syntax:

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"
}
```

How can I make the sonarqube task use another test task?

**Update:**

Got it to work with the below code, made subprojects run their unitTests first to generate required test report data and then run sonarqube task.

```
// Removes the dependency on main test task and runs unitTests for test code coverage statistics
tasks['sonarqube'].with {
    dependsOn.clear()
    subprojects.each { dependsOn("${it.name}:unitTests") }
}
```

dependsOn.clear() clears all dependencies, so if there were multiple, I would probably have to do something like

```
taskName.enabled=false
```

and then re-enable it after the task was done unless there is a easier way to do it? I've tried dependsOn.remove("test") but that didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sonarqube` tasks simply depends on the `test` task by default, according to [the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-Taskdependencies):

> To meet these needs, the plugins adds a task dependency from sonarqube on test if the java plugin is applied.

You can easily remove this task dependency and add your own ones:

```
task unitTest {
    doLast {
        println "I'm a unit test"
    }
}

tasks['sonarqube'].with {
    dependsOn.clear()
    dependsOn unitTest
}
```

Now, only the `unitTest` task (and its dependencies) will be executed whenever you execute the `sonarqube` task. Please note, that `dependsOn` is just a list of dependency entries. You can modify it in many different ways.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, what is your preferred way of changing individual dependencies as mentioned in my updated question?

Comment: I don't understand why the `sonarqube` task depending on the `test` task by default results in all tasks of type `Test` being run.